# Infinite intersection of frontiers

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space and $f\colon X\to X$ a homeomorphism. Let $\delta >0$, define closed sets $B_n=D[f^n(x),\delta]$ (closed ball of center $f^{n}(x)$ with radius $\delta$ in $X$).

I want to prove this inclusion:

$$\partial\left(\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}f^{-n}(B_n)\right)\subset \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}\partial(f^{-n}(B_n)),$$

but I think that I am missing an additional condition on $f$, I appreciate if you could help me find this condition on $f$.

Comment: There's definitely an additional condition missing. Let $X = [0,1]$, $x = 0$, and $0 < \delta < 1$. For $f(t) = \sqrt{t}$, we have $f^{-1}(B_n) = [0, \delta^{2^n}]$, so the intersection is $\{0\} = \partial \{0\}$, yet $\partial f^{-n}(B_n) = \{\delta^{2^n}\} \neq \{0\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: $\partial f^{-n}(B_n)=\{ 0, \delta^{2^n}\}$ ?

Comment: No, $\{0\}$ is an interior point of $f^{-n}(B_n)$ for all $n$. You can extend the example to $[-1,1]$ and set $f(t) = t$ for $t \leqslant 0$, then $f^{-n}(B_n) = [-\delta,\delta^{2^n}]$. That should avoid being led astray by the fact that $0$ is a boundary point of the sets **as subsets of** $\mathbb{R}$ (not as subsets of $[0,1]$).

Comment: thanks for the clarification